# SQL filtro de data no timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, query, timestamp

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT name, commission, timestamp, state_name
FROM magry_awoaffiliate_commission c
INNER JOIN magry_users u ON (c.user_id = u.id)
INNER JOIN magry_virtuemart_userinfos v ON (c.user_id = v.virtuemart_user_id)
INNER JOIN magry_virtuemart_states using (virtuemart_state_id)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

E quero filtrar apenas o período de janeiro de 2017 por exemplo, como faço?

Abaixo o resultado da query

```
name    | comission | timestamp  | state_name
Leticia | 3.76800   | 1489702437 | Paraná
José    | 7.76000   | 1489614271 | São paulo
```

e por ai segue abaixo outros resultados.

Comment: Depois do último join adicione `WHERE year(timestamp) = 2017 AND month(timestamp) = 1` veja se é isso.

Comment: ele continuou trazendo todos

Comment: Qual banco está usando?

Comment: como assim qual banco? mysql, é isso? (sou iniciante nisso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função [from_unixtime()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) para converter o timestamp em uma data no formato `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss`, com isso use `year()` para extrair o ano e `month()` para o mês.

Adicione isso depois do último join:

```
WHERE year(from_unixtime(timestamp)) = 2017 AND month(from_unixtime(timestamp)) = 1
```

**Baseado em:**

[Convert timestamp to date in MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9251561/1342547)

Comment: Perfeito, valeu!!!!